# Python,как сделать перечисление массива,если это определенный элемент списка

Tags: python

Есть код и условная переменная SomeString ,которая принимает 2 значения.
Как сделать,что если SomeString принимает `Apple`,то перечислит элементы нужного списка?

```
Apl = []
Melon = []
Apl.append('Зеленый')
Apl.append('Кислый')
Melon.append('Большой')
Melon.append('Сладкий')
SomeArr = { 'Apple': Apl, 'Melon': Melon }
```

Comment: Так, например, `if SomeString == 'Apple': print(Apl)`

Comment: нет,у меня SomeString принимает значения только из SomeArr (Apple,Melon),и мне нужно выполнить кое-какую операцию с элементами списков

Comment: В текущей формулировке плохо понятно, что вы хотите, и где у вас здесь должна быть SomeString. Напишите условный пример, как это должно происходить - псевдокодом или на питоне с пропусками в тех местах, которые вы не знаете как реализовать и комментариями, какое поведение в этих местах ожидается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте оператором `in`, что такой ключ есть в словаре и выведите значение по ключу:

```
apls = ['Зеленый', 'Кислый']
melons = ['Большой', 'Сладкий']
my_dict = { 'Apple': Apl, 'Melon': Melon }

some_string = input()
if some_string in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[some_string])
```

Comment: Спасибо,это именно то,что я имел ввиду)